Finding out the perimeter of a graph
I have this graph in R:
library(igraph)

set.seed(123)

n <- 20
g <- sample_gnm(n, m = n * 2, directed = FALSE)

while (!is_connected(g)) {
    # Find disconnected components
    components <- components(g)
    
    
    for (i in 2:components$no) {
        from <- sample(which(components$membership == i), 1)
        to <- sample(which(components$membership == 1), 1)
        g <- add_edges(g, c(from, to))
    }
}

g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)

V(g)$weight <- runif(vcount(g))

layout <- layout_with_fr(g)


plot(g, layout = layout, edge.arrow.size = 0.1, 
     vertex.label = V(g)$name, vertex.size = 15, 
     vertex.label.color = "black", edge.curved = 0,
     vertex.color = "white", edge.color = "black")


I want to find out a list of all nodes that are on the perimeter.
I tried to do it like this (I read about the eccentricity function):
library(igraph)

find_outer_nodes <- function(g) {
    eccentricities <- eccentricity(g)
    
    diameter <- max(eccentricities)
    
    outer_nodes <- which(eccentricities == diameter)
    
    return(outer_nodes)
}

outer_nodes <- find_outer_nodes(g)

print(outer_nodes)

The answer looks like this:
[1]  2  3  7 13 16 18 19 20

Is there a more direct way to do this in R?

Your way is more efficient than what's in the accepted answer, while still being very compact. Note that you don't need return in R, you can just leave the which on the last line of the function. This makes your function even more compact. The "problems" with the accepted answer are: distances() returns a matrix, which has O(n^2) memory usage. diameter() effectively re-runs the computation that distances() has already completed, doubling the computation time. In the end, this will have complexity O(n m) anyway, where n is the vertex count and m is the edge count.

Note that there's already a feature request for a periphery function in igraph. If this is something you want built in, you can add a thumbs up to that issue, or comment on it. But keep in mind that making this a built-in function is only going to provide a minor convenience in the end, it won't speed up things significantly. https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/2027

You could colour the outer nodes like this: V(g)$color <- "azure", and V(g)[outer_nodes]$color <- "red"

If you call a "one-liner" as "a more direct way", probably you can try

Using distances (memory unfriendly)

> V(g)[sort(unique(c(which(distances(g) == diameter(g), TRUE))))]
+ 8/20 vertices, from d1b927a:
[1]  2  3  7 13 16 18 19 20


Using eccentricity (more efficient than distances, see comments from @Szabolcs and benckmark from @Carl Witthoft)

> V(g)[(ec <- eccentricity(g)) == max(ec)]
+ 8/20 vertices, from b0e7de3:
[1]  2  3  7 13 16 18 19 20


As suggested in Szabolics' comment, the "distances" answer is considerably slower.  I bumped the sample size from 20 to 200, and:
microbenchmark(find_outer_nodes(g), justv(g))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 find_outer_nodes(g) 1.683682 1.697150 1.728578 1.710579 1.763058  1.825167   100
            justv(g) 3.858268 4.058359 4.176260 4.070759 4.085874 13.674736   100


If brevity is an aspiration, try this.
# magritte pipes
# https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html
find_outer_nodes_magrittr <-
  function(g) {
    g %>% eccentricity %>% {which(. == max(.))}
  }
# R pipe
g |> find_outer_nodes_magrittr() |> print()


Or equivalently
g %>% eccentricity %>% '=='(max(.)) %>% which
